# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have been searching all over the net for this. I can't seem to find the correct thing to do.

We made a 2d scrolling Android game using the book 'Beginning Android Games.' So far, the things went smooth but when we added a lot of bitmaps, the game crashes on all devices. So we removed the bitmaps and it run on gingerbread, honeycomb, and jellybean devices. But it doesn't really work in ICE CREAM SANDWICH devices and I am getting frustrated.

Hoping you can help me.

Here's the logcat error:

```
09-23 11:22:54.866: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-23 11:22:54.866: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
09-23 11:22:54.866: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
09-23 11:22:54.866: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:549)
09-23 11:22:54.866: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): at framework.implementation.AndroidGraphics.newPixmap(AndroidGraphics.java:49)
09-23 11:22:54.866: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): at game.LoadingScreen.update(LoadingScreen.java:27)
09-23 11:22:54.866: E/AndroidRuntime(3525): at framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:48)
09-23 11:22:54.836: E/dalvikvm-heap(3525): Out of memory on a 3840016-byte allocation.
```

The grow heap went up to 33.98MB

Comment: put on your update from LoadingScreen

Comment: once i also was geting this kind of errors, in my case the problem was in not adding picture for specified screen density, the system was scaling default images to needed density and crashing due to large images, try to add correct scaled images, and see if helps..

Comment: @JRowan The update method from the LoadingScreen class receives float deltaTime and the bitmaps like:

    Assets.buttons = g.newPixmap("buttons.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);

Then it would transfer to game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));

Comment: @Eugen Halca What do you mean to add correct scaled images? Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: try to load your Assets outside the update method, like in the constructor, maybe it loads every time the update runs which is by deltaTime or framerate or whatever and its overloading, i mean update methods usualy run like 100 times a second maybe everytime you call g.newPixmap() it allocates memory for a bitmap each time

Comment: ill put it as an answer you can mark it, i read the same book, have a good one glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to load your Assets outside the update method, like in the constructor, maybe it loads every time the update runs which is by deltaTime or framerate or whatever and its overloading, i mean update methods usualy run like 100 times a second maybe everytime you call g.newPixmap() it allocates memory for a bitmap each time

Answer (score 1):

1.Actually you are using most of the time images. In andorid images are handled by Bitmap, so these bitmaps will consume more "Heap Memory", because of creating more bitmap objects every time while changing the images. So we have to use "Object Pooling method" to avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception.

Here is the link, how to create an Object pooling.

Link:http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/12/recycling-objects-in-android-with-an-object-pool-to-avoid-garbage-collection/

2.In 4.X android version device you can see "Developer Settings" in Settings. In developer setting you have to enable the "Don't keep activities" which is destroyed all the activities in background as soon as possible.

In this case you app activity should not crashed, If its crashed your activity not follow the Android Activity life-cycle.

For your refernces here is the link : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Hi @Androiddevandtester! Is the Object Pooling Method you are talking about, the same as this Pool class? http://www.kilobolt.com/day-5-the-android-game-framework-part-i.html - #10

Comment: @user2805659 ya exactly.

Comment: @Androiddevandtester I already have that class, named Pool.java. And it doesn'y seem to work...

Comment: @user2805659 Then you have to use Eclipse MAT analyses of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Re use the BitmapFactory instance and do not make a new instance for each image that your using.

After the call to decodeStream which takes an InputStream argument, you should free all resources in your concrete implementation of this class. Directly calling close on InputStream does nothing.

Comment: I am actually reusing BitmapFactory in a class called AndroidGraphics, see here: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-6-the-android-game-framework-part-ii.html #2